# Is there any other way of deleting row in SQFLITE flutter because mine not working?

Tags: flutter, dart, sqflite

I have following code that is creating/opening database( local storage ) via sqflite package...

```
Future<Database> _getDatabase() async {
  final dbPath = await sql.getDatabasesPath();
  final db = await sql.openDatabase(
    path.join(dbPath, 'my_list_flutter.db'),
    onCreate: (db, version) {
      return db.execute(
          'CREATE TABLE user_list(id TEXT PRIMARY KEY, name TEXT, quantity INT, unit TEXT, cat_title TEXT)');
    },
    version: 1,
  );
  return db;
}
```

Now I am trying to delete a row based on the item's id using following code....

```
  // DELETING AN ITEM IN THE LIST
  void deleteItem(GroceryItem item) async {
    final id = item.id;
    final db = await _getDatabase();
    final count =
        await db.rawDelete('DELETE FROM user_list WHERE id = ?', [id]);

    print(count);
    state = state.where((e) => e != item).toList();
  }
} // DELETING ITEM ends here
```

count is resulting in 0...
And also I am not getting any error...

I even tried following code but still same result.

```
     final count =  await db.delete('user_list', where: 'id = ?', whereArgs: [id]);
```

Comment: Does your item.id matched with database's id ? Kindly check it

Comment: yes i am manually fetching the id in the database during addition of item. I checked it during deletion.

Comment: one more thing i want to add...please check the following steps to fully understand my problem

Comment: 1 - I open my app and add a new item in the list using add option.

Comment: 2 - The UI is updated as soon as i submit to add, i can see my new item on top.

Comment: 3 - I can delete this item by clicking del icon, the item is deleted and the UI is udated accordingly.

Comment: Your code is right . Try to implement debugger for getting the exact issues .

Comment: 4 - The problem starts when i close the app and restarts it after adding an item. I can see my item in the UI when i restart my app but if i try to delete it now , it wont happen.

Comment: why the deletion logic fails if i restart my app

Comment: Ok, After deleting the item call setState () to regenerate the list. . May be the state issues .

Comment: @RahulKushwaha... I checked your earlier point. Found out there was issue of id. Iwas generating new id even when i was loading the saved data. I have changed the code and it works fine now. Thanks for helping. Cheers.....

Comment: It's great to see this.